# How do I display all wordpress-posts in a custom xml-sheet?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to do it by creating a custom template, but I can't figure out how to do that. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I also need to know how I link to it.

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far? Can you show us some code? What precisely is not working? Custom template is the way to go, though.

Comment: When making a custom template, the get_header is requierd, also, adding <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>, brakes the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps, I wont go into details about how you want to do your XML for the sake of simplicity:

Create a page template file in your current theme folder, like xml_template.php with this code inside:

```
<?
/*
Template Name: XML Template
*/

$qry = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=-1');

/* PREPARE YOUR XML BEFORE THE LOOP */

/* RUN THE LOOP */
if($qry->have_posts()){
    while($qry->have_posts()) {
        $qry->the_post();
        /* DO WHAT YOU WANT WITH EACH POST */
    }
}

/* WHEN THE LOOP IS OVER PREPARE XML FOR OUTPUT */

header('Content-type:text/xml');
/* ECHO OUT THE XML */
?>
```

Create a page in wordpress and then choose the template "XML Template" for it.

Visit that page and have a look!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Wordpress Codex for the [function get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)